# RichFaces and JSF: Where does the fileUpload component upload files?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to use [this fileUpload component example](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf) to work in my own project. However, whenever I upload something, it says it uploads and completes successfully, but I have no idea where on the server it's going. I use the Windows search feature to find the filename of the file I just uploaded, but it doesn't return anything.

According to [this page](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_fileUpload.html#d0e33171), the file should be stored in a temp file somewhere, but a scan of the whole server (again using the Windows search program) turns up nothing. I'm using Oracle WebLogic if that helps.

How can I find out what's happening to the uploaded file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the linked page:

> FileUpload uses two init parameters which should be defined in Filter definition in web.xml:
>
> - **createTempFiles** boolean attribute which defines whether the uploaded files are stored in temporary files or available in listener just as `byte[]` data (`false` for this example).

So, the linked code example stores it in the server's memory in flavor of a `byte[]`. You're supposed to write it to a file *yourself* using [`FileOutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). If you set `createTempFiles` to `true`, then you can obtain a fullworthy [`java.io.File`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object by [`org.richfaces.model.UploadItem#getFile()`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/apidoc_framework/org/richfaces/model/UploadItem.html#getFile%28%29) which in turn provides methods to reveal the actual path, such as [`File#getAbsolutePath()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29).

I would recommend to set it to `true` anyway. Large concurrent uploads from multiple users may cause `OutOfMemoryException`s otherwise. You don't want to have that in production.